# Unable to get ACF repeater field value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created an ACF repeater field on my options page but I'm unable to retrieve the value using [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/). How do I retrieve the repeater value?

Comment: Please show the code by adding a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ACF - Get values from an options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/), you need to add `'option'` as the second parameter in `get_field()`.

See this example:

```php
$variable = get_field('field_name', 'option');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater', 'option') ): ?>

<ul>

<?php while( have_rows('repeater', 'option') ): the_row(); ?>

    <li><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Replace repeater with the name of your field and inside the_sub_field() with what you have included.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get ACF Repeater field you have to use 'echo get_sub_field();' or 'the_sub_field();'
2. For ACF option page you can use the following code:

```
    <?php if( have_rows('repeater_field_name', 'option') ): 
      while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name', 'option') ) : the_row();
       the_sub_field('yourfieldname'); 
     endwhile;
   endif; ?>
```